# Is replacing enum constructs with classes in Java still relevant?

Tags: java, enums

I am reading Effective Java written by Joshua Bloch published in 2008, and one tip is to replace enum constructs with classes.  Here's the example shown from the book.

```
public class Suit {
    private final String name;
    public Suit(String name) { this.name = name; }
    public String toString() { return name; }
    public static final Suit CLUBS = new Suit("clubs");
    public static final Suit DIAMONDS = new Suit("diamonds");
    public static final Suit HEARTS = new Suit("hearts");
    public static final Suit SPADES = new Suit("spades");
}
```

My question is since Java now supports enum type, is it still a good idea to use the approach above?  Here's example of Java enum type.

```
public enum Day {
    SUNDAY, MONDAY, TUESDAY, WEDNESDAY,
    THURSDAY, FRIDAY, SATURDAY 
}
```

Comment: enums in Java are classes.

Comment: For basic enum-like functionality there's no reason not to use simple `enum`s. There are a few advanced little tweaks that you can not do with enums where the type-safe enum pattern can still be applied.

Comment: Read the 2nd edition of the book, it's really worth it, because it covers the new Java features.

Comment: In the book, he's referring to the "C" enum construct, not the Java enum.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The "Effective Java" book has been written well before the introduction of `enum`s into the language, so I would recommend using the `enum` feature instead. Fortunately, Java `enum`s are very versatile, so you can follow Joshua's advice pretty closely using the `enum` feature:

```
public enum Day {
    SUNDAY("Sunday", 0)
,   MONDAY("Monday", 1)
,   TUESDAY("Tuesday", 2)
,   WEDNESDAY("Wednesday", 3)
,   THURSDAY("Thursday", 4)
,   FRIDAY("Friday", 5)
,   SATURDAY("Saturday", 6);

    private String name;
    private int ordinal;
    public String getName() { return name; }
    public int getOrdinal() { return ordinal; }
    public Day(String name, int ordinal) {
        this.name = name;
        this.ordinal = ordinal;
    }
}
```

Comment: EnumSets are a pretty useful construct too.

Comment: It's worth noting that the 2nd edition does cover the use of enums.

Comment: Thanks dasblinkenlight, your example is very useful.

Comment: Why the ordinal here? Enums have a builtin ordinal() method which does exactly what you do.

Comment: @fge That's only an illustration - I wanted to add a second parameter to pass to the constructor, to illustrate the point that you can pass multiple parameters. The "day of week" `enum` has too few things logically associated with it, though, so I decided to add an ordinal of my own.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I also have question related to enums [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47956136/how-can-i-represent-key-with-list-of-values-for-each-environment-type-in-an-enum/). Wanted to see whether we can represent that easily with enums or not.

Answer (score 2):

I think that the idea is exactly opposite. If you have enum-like structure - use `enum`.

Your class example is not exactly suits to the enum you wrote. First, it cannot be compiled because it contains several fields named `CLUBS`. Second, enum contains days that are not mentioned in your class.

Comment: oops!  You caught my typo.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, java compiles enum-s to `public static final` objects.
You can check this by viewing enum .class files with `javap` (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/windows/javap.html).

Comment: only if the source code doesn't matter, and I'd say the source is very important.