# Send data in multiple ways depending on how you want to send it

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, bytebuffer, single-responsibility-principle

I have bunch of keys and values that I want to send to our messaging queue by packing them in one byte array. I will make one byte array of all the keys and values which should always be less than 50K and then send to our messaging queue.

**Packet class**:

```
public final class Packet implements Closeable {
  private static final int MAX_SIZE = 50000;
  private static final int HEADER_SIZE = 36;

  private final byte dataCenter;
  private final byte recordVersion;
  private final long address;
  private final long addressFrom;
  private final long addressOrigin;
  private final byte recordsPartition;
  private final byte replicated;
  private final ByteBuffer itemBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(MAX_SIZE);
  private int pendingItems = 0;

  public Packet(final RecordPartition recordPartition) {
    this.recordsPartition = (byte) recordPartition.getPartition();
    this.dataCenter = Utils.LOCATION.get().datacenter();
    this.recordVersion = 1;
    this.replicated = 0;
    final long packedAddress = new Data().packAddress();
    this.address = packedAddress;
    this.addressFrom = 0L;
    this.addressOrigin = packedAddress;
  }

  private void addHeader(final ByteBuffer buffer, final int items) {
    buffer.put(dataCenter).put(recordVersion).putInt(items).putInt(buffer.capacity())
        .putLong(address).putLong(addressFrom).putLong(addressOrigin).put(recordsPartition)
        .put(replicated);
  }

  private void sendData() {
    if (itemBuffer.position() == 0) {
      // no data to be sent
      return;
    }
    final ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(MAX_SIZE);
    addHeader(buffer, pendingItems);
    buffer.put(itemBuffer);
    SendRecord.getInstance().sendToQueueAsync(address, buffer.array());
    // SendRecord.getInstance().sendToQueueAsync(address, buffer.array());
    // SendRecord.getInstance().sendToQueueSync(address, buffer.array());
    // SendRecord.getInstance().sendToQueueSync(address, buffer.array(), socket);
    itemBuffer.clear();
    pendingItems = 0;
  }

  public void addAndSendJunked(final byte[] key, final byte[] data) {
    if (key.length > 255) {
      return;
    }
    final byte keyLength = (byte) key.length;
    final byte dataLength = (byte) data.length;

    final int additionalSize = dataLength + keyLength + 1 + 1 + 8 + 2;
    final int newSize = itemBuffer.position() + additionalSize;
    if (newSize >= (MAX_SIZE - HEADER_SIZE)) {
      sendData();
    }
    if (additionalSize > (MAX_SIZE - HEADER_SIZE)) {
      throw new AppConfigurationException("Size of single item exceeds maximum size");
    }

    final ByteBuffer dataBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(data);
    final long timestamp = dataLength > 10 ? dataBuffer.getLong(2) : System.currentTimeMillis();
    // data layout
    itemBuffer.put((byte) 0).put(keyLength).put(key).putLong(timestamp).putShort(dataLength)
        .put(data);
    pendingItems++;
  }

  @Override
  public void close() {
    if (pendingItems > 0) {
      sendData();
    }
  }
}
```

Below is the way I am sending data. As of now my design only permits to send data asynchronously by calling `sendToQueueAsync` method in above `sendData()` method.

```
  private void validateAndSend(final RecordPartition partition) {
    final ConcurrentLinkedQueue<DataHolder> dataHolders = dataHoldersByPartition.get(partition);

    final Packet packet = new Packet(partition);

    DataHolder dataHolder;
    while ((dataHolder = dataHolders.poll()) != null) {
      packet.addAndSendJunked(dataHolder.getClientKey().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8),
          dataHolder.getProcessBytes());
    }
    packet.close();
  }
```

Now I need to extend my design so that I can send data in three different ways. It is up to user to decide which way he wants to send data, either "sync" or "async".

- I need to send data asynchronously by calling `sender.sendToQueueAsync` method.
- or I need to send data synchronously by calling `sender.sendToQueueSync` method.
- or I need to send data synchronously but on a particular socket by calling `sender.sendToQueueSync` method. In this case I need to pass `socket` variable somehow so that `sendData` knows about this variable.

**SendRecord class**:

```
public class SendRecord {
  private final ScheduledExecutorService executorService = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(2);
  private final Cache<Long, PendingMessage> cache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder().maximumSize(1000000)
      .concurrencyLevel(100).build();

  private static class Holder {
    private static final SendRecord INSTANCE = new SendRecord();
  }

  public static SendRecord getInstance() {
    return Holder.INSTANCE;
  }

  private SendRecord() {
    executorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        handleRetry();
      }
    }, 0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  }

  private void handleRetry() {
    List<PendingMessage> messages = new ArrayList<>(cache.asMap().values());
    for (PendingMessage message : messages) {
      if (message.hasExpired()) {
        if (message.shouldRetry()) {
          message.markResent();
          doSendAsync(message);
        } else {
          cache.invalidate(message.getAddress());
        }
      }
    }
  }

  // called by multiple threads concurrently
  public boolean sendToQueueAsync(final long address, final byte[] encodedRecords) {
    PendingMessage m = new PendingMessage(address, encodedRecords, true);
    cache.put(address, m);
    return doSendAsync(m);
  }

  // called by above method and also by handleRetry method
  private boolean doSendAsync(final PendingMessage pendingMessage) {
    Optional<SocketHolder> liveSocket = SocketManager.getInstance().getNextSocket();
    ZMsg msg = new ZMsg();
    msg.add(pendingMessage.getEncodedRecords());
    try {
      // this returns instantly
      return msg.send(liveSocket.get().getSocket());
    } finally {
      msg.destroy();
    }
  }

  // called by send method below
  private boolean doSendAsync(final PendingMessage pendingMessage, final Socket socket) {
    ZMsg msg = new ZMsg();
    msg.add(pendingMessage.getEncodedRecords());
    try {
      // this returns instantly
      return msg.send(socket);
    } finally {
      msg.destroy();
    }
  }

  // called by multiple threads to send data synchronously without passing socket
  public boolean sendToQueueSync(final long address, final byte[] encodedRecords) {
    PendingMessage m = new PendingMessage(address, encodedRecords, false);
    cache.put(address, m);
    try {
      if (doSendAsync(m)) {
        return m.waitForAck();
      }
      return false;
    } finally {
      cache.invalidate(address);
    }
  }

  // called by a threads to send data synchronously but with socket as the parameter
  public boolean sendToQueueSync(final long address, final byte[] encodedRecords, final Socket socket) {
    PendingMessage m = new PendingMessage(address, encodedRecords, false);
    cache.put(address, m);
    try {
      if (doSendAsync(m, socket)) {
        return m.waitForAck();
      }
      return false;
    } finally {
      cache.invalidate(address);
    }
  }

  public void handleAckReceived(final long address) {
    PendingMessage record = cache.getIfPresent(address);
    if (record != null) {
      record.ackReceived();
      cache.invalidate(address);
    }
  }
}
```

Callers will only call either of below three methods:

- sendToQueueAsync by passing two parameters
- sendToQueueSync by passing two parameters
- sendToQueueSync by passing three parameters

How should I design my `Packet` and `SendRecord` class so that I can tell `Packet` class that this data needs to be send in either of above three ways to my messaging queue. It is up to user to decide which way he wants to send data to messaging queue. As of now the way my `Packet` class is structured, it can send data only in one way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your best option is the Strategy pattern (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern).

Using this pattern, you can encapsulate the behaviour of each type of "send", for example, an AsynchronousSend class, a SynchronousSend class and an AsynchronousSocketSend class. (You could probably come up with better names). The `Packet` class can then decide, based on some logic, which class to use to send the data to the queue.

Comment: Three different class to send same data? Don't you think it's too much? Or maybe I am thinking it in a wrong way.

Comment: @user1950349 Yes, I don't see why not. It keeps classes having a single responsibility. Small classes are always preferable.

Comment: hmm But what logic I will add in `Packet` class that decide which code to call to send data?

Comment: @user1950349 Well, I don't know exactly what logic you need, but I'm assuming you will need the same logic regardless of the design you chose to use.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see the definition of `sender` in `Packet`.  I assume it is defined as a private instance variable?

The design indeed needs to be fixed.
By having the `Packet` class do the sending, the design violates the [Single responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).  There should be a separate (possibly abstract) class that prepares the data to be sent (prepares a `java.nio.Buffer` instance) and it can have one or more sub classes, one of which returns a `java.nio.ByteBuffer` instance.

A separate class that gets a `Buffer` and performs the sending.  This (possibly abstract) class can have sub classes for the different sending platforms and methods.

then, you need another class that implements the [Builder pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern). Clients that wish to send packets, use the builder to specify concrete `Packet` and `Sender` (and possibly other needed properties, like a socket number) and then call `send()` that does the sending.

Comment: Yeah I omitted the `sender` stuff. In general it can be anything. A class which has three different methods to send data. In my case I was having singleton factory class and I was just calling `Sender.getInstance().sendToQueueAsync` method only but I need to extend this so that I can call whatever I want to? Can you provide an example so that I can understand properly? As of now little bit confuse..

Answer (score 2):

First of you you need to have a clear answer to the question of who (or what part of your code) is responsible for deciding what sending method is to be used.

- Is it based on some external configuration?
- Is it based on some (dynamic) user decision?
- Is it based on partition being processed?
- Is it based on message content?

(Just to name a few possibilities)

The answer will determine what structure would be most appropriate.

Nevertheless, It is clear that current `sendData()` method is the place to put the decision to effect. Thus, this method needs to be provided the implementation to use. The actual `send()` likely is similar in all cases. It suggest to encapsulate the *sending* functionality into an interface that does provide the `send()` method signature:

```
send(address, data);
```

If the target socket is to be determined from the actual message data, then you might prefer a general signature of

```
send(address, data, socket);
```

and make that socket value optional or use a specific value for encoding "no specific socket" cases. Otherwise the you could use a specific `Sender` instance that has the socket passed in via constructor.

I currently do not see a valid reason from what you have provided that calls for implementing the three different send methods as three different methods within one class. If common code is a reason then using a common base class will allow for appropriate sharing.

That leaves the question how the specific instance of the appropriate `Sender` implementation is to be made available within `sendData()`.

If the sending strategy is to be determined outside of `sendData()` the implementation has to be handed in. Either as a parameter or as a field from the current class instance. If the local data is what is determining the sending strategy you should delegate the determination of the proper implementation to a *selection class* that will return the proper implementation. The call will then look similar to:

```
startegySelector.selectStartegy(selectionParameters).send(address,data);
```

Though, without having a clearer picture on what is fixed and what is variable in the execution, it is hard suggesting *best approach*.

In case the decision is based on data, the whole selection and diversion process is local to `Packet` class.

If the decision is made externally to `Packet` you might want to get a sending strategy implementation at that location and pass that as parameter down to `addAndSendJunked()` (or more precisely down to `sendData()`.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. It is based on user decision always which means user can decide how they want to send it. I need to have a way where I can send same data in many ways so that user can choose how they want to send it. As of now in `sendData` method, I am sending everything as async by calling this method `sendToQueueAsync` but in general I need a way by which I can send same data through 3 different ways. My sender class is `thread safe singleton factory` with all those three methods to send data to messaging queue.

Answer (score 2):

You could have an enum class, say PacketTransportionMode which would have a 'send' method overridden for different types of enum values (SYNC,ASYNC,SYNC_ON_SOCKET), example: .

```
public enum PacketTransportionMode {
SYNC {
    @Override
    public boolean send(Packet packet) {
        byte[] message = packet.getMessage();
        Socket socket = new Socket(packet.getReceiverHost(), packet.getReceiverPort());
        DataOutputStream dOut = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        dOut.writeInt(message.length); // write length of the message
        dOut.write(message);           // write the message
        return true;
    }
},
ASYNC {
    @Override
    public boolean send(Packet packet) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }
},
SYNC_ON_SOCKET

{
    @Override
    public boolean send(Packet packet) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

};
public abstract boolean send(Packet packet);
}
```

Also, in packet class, introduce transportationMode variable. In packet.send() implementation, this.packetTransportationMode.send(this) can be  called

Client can create packet object and set its transportationMode in the beginning, similar to setting RecordPartition. Then client can call packet.send();

Or instead of putting transportationMode variable inside packet class and calling this.packetTransportationMode.send(this), client can also create Packet object and call PacketTransportionMode.SYNC.send(packet) directly.

Comment: Interesting idea. Do you think you can provide an example basis on my code so that I can understand better? As of now, I am kinda confuse on how will this work.

Answer (score 2):

use enum varibale for defining the types of send message

```
public enum TypeToSend {
    async, sync, socket 
}

public final class Packet implements Closeable {
TypeToSend typeToSend;
public Packet(TypeToSend typeToSend) {
        this.typeToSend = typeToSend;
    }
switch(typeToSend){
     case async:{}
     case sync:{}
     case socket:{}
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Strategy. Difference from Kerri Brown's answer is that Packet should not make decision between strategies. Instead, decide it outside of the Packet class.

Single sending strategy interface should be implemented by 3 different classes, each corresponding to one of the mentioned sending approaches. Inject strategy interface into the Packet, so that Packet does not have to change regardless of which strategy it deals with.

You said it must be based on user's choice. So you can ask user upfront, what is the choice, and then based on that, instantiate the implementation of a sending strategy interface which corresponds to the user's choice. Then, instantiate the Packet with the selected sending strategy instance.

If you feel that later on choice may not depend on the user, then make that a Factory. So then your solution becomes combination of Factory and Strategy.

In that case, Packet can have Factory interface injected. Packet asks Factory to give it the sending strategy. Next it sends using the strategy acquired from the factory. Factory asks for user's input, which later on can be replaced by making a choice based on some other condition, and not the user input. You achieve that by implementing Factory interface differently in the future and injecting that new factory instead of this one (i.e. user input based factory vs some other condition based factory).

Both approaches will give you a code following Open/Close principle. But try not to overengineer if you don't really need a factory.